# Cannot connect Wifly to Arduino

Tags: c++, connection, embedded, wifi, arduino

I am just an Arduino beginner. I bought an Arduino Uno and a Wifly shield yesterday and I am not able to run the Wifly_Test example program come with WiFlySerial library.

When I look at Serial Monitor, I only saw 2 lines are printed out

```
1.Starting WiFly Tester.
2.Free memory:XXXX
```

How can I know that the Wifly Sheild that I bought is not faulty?
I soldered the heard ping to Wifly Shield and stacked it to Aurduino Uno and I can see the LEDs blinking on the Wifly Shield.

Do I need to reset the Wifly Sheild? How do I reset it?

Please point me to the most simple example on how to connect to the router.

Comment: Might this not be a better for for the [Electrical Engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)? Or the [Arduino Forum](http://arduino.cc/forum/) for that matter?

Comment: I saw some questions and answer about Arudino in here. So I think I might get some opinion here.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=25129).  I am struggling to understand what "*the heard ping*" is or what "*stacked it to*" might mean here.

Comment: I believe he means header pins and plugged the board into the Arduino.

Comment: Yes it was my typo. Thx Jeff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who tried to answer me. I finally solved my problem by using Arduino 0023 instead of 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

I have also bought the shield and had trouble to start with.

If you have soldered the pins to the shield that should be fine but make sure you check they all have a connection and that they don't have solder running down the legs of the pins as this causes the shield to be temperamental.

Run the code below which is from the WiFly library (alpha 2 version) that can be found here:
http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=25216&start=30

Once you see that the shield has connected it will ask for an input, type $$$ and press enter... you have now entered the command line and CMD will be displayed.

If you do not know your network settings type scan and this will display them.
Then set your authentication by typing set wlan auth 3 (Mixed WPA1 & WPA2-PSK) or set wlan auth 4 (WPA2-PSK) this depends on the type of authentication you ise so pick the write one for your network.

Then type set wlan phrase YourPharsePhrase (Change YourPharsePhrase to whatever your WPA key is)
Then type join YourSSIDName (Change YourSSIDName to whatever your network name is)

You see something like this: 
    join YourSSIDName
    Auto-Assoc YourSSIDName chan=1 mode=MIXED SCAN OK
    Joining YourSSIDName now..
    <2.15> Associated!
    DHCP: Start
    DHCP in 1234ms, lease=86400s
    IF=UP
    DHCP=ON
    IP=10.0.0.116:2000
    NM=255.255.255.0
    GW=10.0.0.1
    Listen on 2000

you are now connected to your network.

Hopefully this will get you up and running.
**N.B. REMEMBER TO CAREFULLY CHECK YOUR PINS! I had great trouble with mine because only a small amount of solder is needed but enough to get a good connection, the balance of this was minute but enough that it wouldn't work.  I used a magnifying to check mine in the end.**

```
#include "WiFly.h" // We use this for the preinstantiated SpiSerial object.


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SPI UART on WiFly Shield terminal tool");
  Serial.println("--------------------------------------");  
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("This is a tool to help you troubleshoot problems with the WiFly shield.");
  Serial.println("For consistent results unplug & replug power to your Arduino and WiFly shield.");
  Serial.println("(Ensure the serial monitor is not open when you remove power.)");  
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("Attempting to connect to SPI UART...");
  SpiSerial.begin();
  Serial.println("Connected to SPI UART.");
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println(" * Use $$$ (with no line ending) to enter WiFly command mode. (\"CMD\")");
  Serial.println(" * Then send each command followed by a carriage return.");
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("Waiting for input.");
  Serial.println();    

}


void loop() {
  // Terminal routine

  // Always display a response uninterrupted by typing
  // but note that this makes the terminal unresponsive
  // while a response is being received.
  while(SpiSerial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.write(SpiSerial.read());
  }

  if(Serial.available()) { // Outgoing data
    //SpiSerial.print(Serial.read(), BYTE);
    SpiSerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I have solved my problem by using different IDE version. Btw, where did you enter $$$ ? In Serial Monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I forgot to mention , you reset the shield by going to the WiFly library and going to: WiFly/tools/HardwareFactoryReset

Then open the serial monitor and type in any character and this will start the reset.